# Error while customizing selinux policy for domain

Tags: selinux, errors

I am following the steps outlined under this [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/writing-a-custom-selinux-policy_using-selinux) to customize selinux policy for specific domains (types).

For the domain `systemd_tmpfiles_t`, I get the following suggestion from `audit2allow` for a denial logged:

```
require{
        type default_t;
        type systemd_tmpfiles_t;
        class file map;
}

#================================systemd_tmpfiles_t=======================

#!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'domain_can_mmap_files'
allow systemd_tmpfiles_t default_t:file map;
```

Based on the procedure outlined in the above link, I do

```
echo "allow systemd_tmpfiles_t default_t:file map" >> custom_rules.te
```

and get the following error:

```
ERROR 'unknown type default_t'
```

I had generated the `custom_rules.te` by means of the following command:

```
sepolicy generate --customize -d systemd_tmpfiles_t -n custom_rules.te
```

And in the generated `custom_rules.te`, I can see only the following rule:

```
gen_require('
             type systemd_tmpfiles_t
')
```

How can I resolve this issue causes due to the type `default_t` not being known to the generated `custom_rules.te`?

Appreciate your thoughts.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default_t type is missing from your generated custom_rules.te file.

You should open the custom_rules.te and modify the gen_require block like that:

```
gen_require(`
    type systemd_tmpfiles_t;
    type default_t;
`)
```

Then save the file and compile again like this:

```
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile custom_rules.pp
sudo semodule -i custom_rules.pp
```